# Why the date format (actually language) is different in two aspx page

Tags: asp.net, date, localization

I have 2 aspx pages both gets date data from the same database table (same date field) but one shows the date like 04.09.2009, the other shows 9/4/2009. Both uses same format.

Any ideas? I am not familiar with web programming.

Cheers,
Burak

Comment: What is the language for your browser?

Do either of the pages have a language specified?

Is the date being passed to both views in the same format - i.e. As a 'Date', rather than a 'String'.

Some sample code may help to shed light on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can specify the UICulture and Culture in the asp server tag (located at the top of your .aspx file), check if they are different.